# Using JRBeanCollectionDataSource

Tags: jasper-reports, jpa-2.0

I am generating the reports using ireport-4.5.0. I am using `JRBeanCollectionDatasource`. To this datasource I am sending the list of objects. I am using JPA query to get the result list.

In this query if I give `SELECT m from mobile m` it is working fine and generating the report, but if I give `SELECT m.title,m.gender from mobile m` then it is giving exception. It is not able to find the attribute.

What to do to resolve this issue? Can any one tell me how to resolve this? I am strucked up here from so many days. Sorry for my poor English.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second query **does not** return a collection of beans, but rather a collection of arrays (Object[]), that all have two elements: title and gender. The array does not have properties (you cannot call `getGender` of `getTitle` on it), and hence the exception.

You have a vast array of solutions:

- write a simple bean (eg. TitleGener) that only has two properties: gender and title. It should also have a constructor that initializes both of them. Then change your JPA query to: `SELECT new my.utils.TitleGender(m.title,m.gender) from mobile m`. This way you will get a collection of beans that actually do have the required properties. This is the quickest fix.
- do not `JRBeanCollectionDataSource` at all, just use the standard JDBC data source. You do not seem to understand how JPA works anyway, so it is doubtful if you need it. This is - in my opinion - the best choice.
- write a simple, specialized `JRDataSource` that wraps Object[]. The interface only has two methods and is simple to implement - the main point will be translation from the name of the property to its index int Object[], in your case the translation will be hard-coded. This is what I would do.